# Apend xml content to another xml (but without the header part) on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, append, concatenation

I have an app for Android that downloads a xml from the web. I managed to update that xml by appending another xml to it.
But I don't want my xml to contain the second xml's header. I want it to be continuous (not like it was composed by several files).
How can I append the second xml to the first without the firsts 4 - 5 lines (the header that I'm not interested about)?
I want that because I get an error when parsing the concateneted xml with sax. (my guess is that the second one's header is the reason).
Thanks.

Comment: The SAX error could be from the second XML header. But it could also be because an XML document can only have a single root node. You can't just append one XML file to another (even if you get rid of the second header).

Comment: Ted Hopp says right: XML must have only one root element. So do your XMLs have the same roots? And do you want to merge them?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 xmls with the same structure. It's a report per day. Each day has it's own xml and I want to put all days in one xml file with the same structure.